# iOS 13 Dark theme settings in app don't change alert controller call phone number style

Tags: swift, system-calls, uialertview, ios13, ios-darkmode

In my app, I want use only light mode. In AppDelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions I use:

```
if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
             UIWindow.appearance().overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .light
         }
```

and it work well. But when I use:

```
  if let url = URL(string: "tel://\(alertItems[indexPath.row - 1].phoneNumber)"), UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
    UIApplication.shared.open(url)
```

alert controller appears with system settings theme (dark for example).
How I can solve this problem?

Comment: I don't think you can control the theme of the system alert...

Comment: Alert controller will us the semantic UI Element colours - have you redefined them at all?

Comment: @flanker, no, how I can do it for system alert controller?

Comment: You can't (easily) do it just or a specific view - they are common across all system views - but more to the point if they are working for everything else this isn't how to fix (or the cause of) your problem.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of this:

```
if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
        UIWindow.appearance().overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .light
}
```

You can do: add this new key `UIUserInterfaceStyle` to `Info.plist` and set its value to `Light`. and check `alert controller` appears with light mode.

```
<key>UIUserInterfaceStyle</key>
<string>Light</string>
```

If you are force light/dark mode in your whole application regardless of the user's settings by adding the key `UIUserInterfaceStyle` to your `Info.plist` file and setting its value to either `Light` or `Dark`.

Comment: now my AppDelegate contains only  "if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
      UIView.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UIAlertController.self]).overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .light"
    } and Info.plist contains  "<key>UIUserInterfaceStyle</key>
<string>Light</string>". But it doesn't help